# Difference between NDSolve and RecurrenceTable

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, difference-equations

I have the following system which I model as difference equations and solve with `RecurrenceTable`:

```
sol = RecurrenceTable[{
   x1[n + 1] == 1/3 x2[n] + 1/3 x3[n] + 1/3 x4[n],
   x2[n + 1] == 1/3 x1[n] + 1/3 x3[n] + 1/3 x4[n],
   x3[n + 1] == 1/3 x1[n] + 1/3 x2[n] + 1/3 x4[n],
   x4[n + 1] == 1/3 x1[n] + 1/3 x2[n] + 1/3 x3[n], x1[0] == 0.1, 
   x2[0] == 1, x3[0] == 1, x4[0] == 1}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, {n, 0, 20}]
```

and which converges to some value as expected given that the Matrix M of coefficients has a spectral radius of <=1:

```
M = {{0, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3}, {1/3, 0, 1/3, 1/3}, {1/3, 1/3, 0, 1/3}, {1/3,
     1/3, 1/3, 0}};
Eigensystem@M
```

Now I use `NDSolve` for the same system:

```
sol = NDSolve[{
   x1'[n] == 1/3 x2[n] + 1/3 x3[n] + 1/3 x4[n],
   x2'[n] == 1/3 x1[n] + 1/3 x3[n] + 1/3 x4[n],
   x3'[n] == 1/3 x1[n] + 1/3 x2[n] + 1/3 x4[n],
   x4'[n] == 1/3 x1[n] + 1/3 x2[n] + 1/3 x3[n], x1[0] == 0.1, 
   x2[0] == 1, x3[0] == 1, x4[0] == 1}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, {n, 0, 20}]
```

and the solutions go to infinity. However the Matrix did not change and I would have expected that the system also converges.

Can somebody explain to me how these differences arise (or what I'm doing wrong)?

Comment: The solutions differ because they're different systems.  Of course the first is discrete-time and the second is continuous-time.  However the biggest difference is that `x1'[n]` is discretized as `(x1[n+1]-x1[n])/dn` where `dn` is the step-size (`1`).  So to make them more comparable, you need to subtract `x[n]` from the right-hand side of the differential equations.  In this case, they match in long-term behavior.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The discrete-time system can be approximated with a continuous-time system using [`ToContinuousTimeModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToContinuousTimeModel.html) to produce approximate results.

```
ssmd = StateSpaceModel[{M, Table[{0}, 4]}, SamplingPeriod -> 1];
OutputResponse[{%, {0.1, 1, 1, 1}}, Table[0, 20]];
pd = ListLinePlot[%, DataRange -> {0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotMarkers -> Automatic];

ssmc = ToContinuousTimeModel[ssmd, Method -> "ForwardRectangularRule"];
OutputResponse[{%, {0.1, 1, 1, 1}}, 0, {t, 0, 20}];
pc = Plot[%, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Dashed]

Show[pd, pc]
```

The dashed response of the approximated system and the original system.
[image]

The approximated matrix of the continuous-time system is different

```
Normal[ssmc][[1]]
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  -1 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
>  \frac{1}{3} & -1 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
>  \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & -1 & \frac{1}{3} \\
>  \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & -1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

and will have a different eigensystem.

([`OutputResponse`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OutputResponse.html) is essentially using [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html) and [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) under the hood.)